# Converting Address Sequence to Reference String In Page replacement

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual

Recently when i was going through the basic concepts of Operating Systems , In the unit Virtual Memory Management(Albert Silberschatz 7th Edition) , I came across this concept for page replacement-

For example, if we trace a particular process, we might record the following
address sequence:
0100,0432,0101,0612,0102,0103,0104,0101,0611,0102,0103,
0104,0101,0610,0102,0103,0104,0101,0609,0102,0105
At 100 bytes per page, this sequence is reduced to the following reference
string:
1, 4, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6,

I could not possibly understand how the recorded address sequence could be converted to reference string.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, yet another confused reader of that book. To begin with, a page size is always going to be a power of 2. So let's make your question marginally realistic and say that those are all hexadecimal digits.

What you are doing here is then converting byte accesses into page references. The zeroth page starts at 0000 and ends at 00FF. The 1st page  starts at 0100 ends at 01FF. Thus a reference to the 0100 is the first byte of page 1.

The page that starts at 0400 extends to 04FF. Thus the address 0432 is to the 4th page.

I don't know what point the authors are trying to get to.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that the 2nd digit from the MSB is the page reference string , for eg: if it's 0100 then the reference string is 1 , similarly 0323 gives 3 and so on.., and if you find a combination of 0100 0102 0113 then , all the three combined gives one reference string i.e 1. But I don't have any proper evidence in support of this logic or exactly to what the writers wanted to infer.

Answer (score 0):

Reference String is set of successfully **unique** pages referred in the given list of Virtual Address or Logical Address.

Consider the Logical Address given as 3001,1002,1003,2001,2002,3003,2601,2602,1004,1005,1507,1510,2003,2008,3501,3603,4001,4002,1020,1021 and page size as 250 .

The Reference String of the given memory address sequence is calculated as

**Reference String = Logical Address / Page Size**

String Reference :  12 , 4 , 8 , 12 , 10 , 4 , 6 , 8 , 14 , 16 ,  4

Answer (score 0):

**Address sequence**: 0100, 0432, 0101, 0612, 0102, 0103, 0104, 0101, 0611, 0102, 0103, 0104, 0101, 0610, 0102, 0103, 0104, 0101, 0609, 0102, 0105
**Page size**: 100 bytes
**Reference string**: 1 4 1 6 1 6 1 6 1 6 1

The reference in the reference string is obtained by dividing (integer division) each address reference by the page size.

**Reference = Address / Page Size**

Consecutive occurrences of the same reference are replaced by a single reference.

Source:
https://notesmilenge.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/mod3b.pdf